# Plasmashell's increasing (private) memory usage

Tags: fedora, kde5

I have a Lenovo T530 laptop with 12G RAM, 1TB HDD, i5 processor running (a freshly installed) Fedora Core 27 with KDE desktop. The kernel is 4.15.10-300.

I have noticed (actually since Fedora 26) that after a while (24 hours, plus or minus 12 hours) I would have to power-cycle the laptop because the drive light would be on constant and nothing would respond - not even the mouse. Usually this would be either in the morning, or after I've been away for a while and can't wake it up.

Today I finally started watching with `systemmonitor` and after 3hrs 40min of uptime it tells me:

> The process plasmashell (with pid 4895) is using approximately 8.4 GB of memory.
>   It is using 8.4 GB privately, 270.1 KB for pixmaps, and a further 64.8 MB that is, or could be, shared with other programs.

That 8.4G started out as a whispy 200M when I first boot the system.

Looking at the Library Usage section I see, in the Private column:

> 8557944 KB    /i915 (deleted)

Am I dealing with a memory leak here? What does `(deleted)` mean? And, more importantly, how can I get back the super-stable KDE desktop I had with Fedora 24 when I didn't have to reboot for weeks, sometimes months, on end (aside from going back to Fedora 24), and I can look with derision upon my Winows frends who have to reboot at least once a week?

Comment: Are you using any KDE widgets?

Comment: I do but nothing I haven't used before. I suppose you'll be wanting me to shut them down to see if that has any effect.

Comment: So, I have removed every widget from my desktop and after 1:42 plasmashell is up to 5.4GB, with that `/i915 (deleted)` using 5,333,068KB. Any other ideas?

Comment: Looks like the problem is the slideshow background changer. I disabled it on the desktop and changed to a static picture and the system has been Rick solid ever since. `journalctl | grep kf5` shows tons of `kf5.kpackage: No metadata file in the package, expected it at ....` one for everytime the background changed.

Comment: Yeah it seems like there's some issue with memory leaks in KDE Widgets. It's a shame but I'm glad you've at least found the source of the issue. May I suggest using [`feh`](https://feh.finalrewind.org/) with a Bash script to emulate a slideshow background?

Comment: For anyone still havimg this issue, the specific widget is the background changer. Seems to be fixed in Fedora 28.